# How to save an output in console as a variable in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, output, hierarchy

I am doing the project from web development course, and I want to modify it a bit, but I'm stuck. I want to save this output -> response.outputs[0].data.regions[0].data.concepts[0].name
as a variable, and then pass it to a child component, however, all the ways I tried to do it didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

````
 ``` onSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input});
    app.models
    .predict(
      Clarifai.RANDOM_MODEL,
      this.state.input)
      .then(
          function (response){
           console.log(response.outputs[0].data.regions[0].data.concepts[0].name);
        },
        function(err){
          console.log(err)
        }
      );
    } ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Inside the `then` callback, store the data in the component's **state**.

When you render the child component, pass the data from the state through a property.

Since the state might not have the desired value yet, you need to test for that and provide suitable alternative content.

e.g.

```
if (myStateVariable) {
    return <Foo value={myStateVariable} />
}
return <LoadingIndicator />
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried state, and later I also realized that the problem was that probably the output didn't come out yet, but I didn't think of a conditional! I will try it :)